# How to make sudo ask for password each time specific commands are run?

Tags: sudo

I run ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04
I want to make sure that the users do not accidentally poweroff or reboot remote machines, yet I need to give them the ability to poweroff/reboot after their password is typed in

So, I have some lines in our sudoers like:

```
Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=10

odev1 ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get,/bin/mount,/usr/bin/minicom
odev1 ALL=(ALL)    PASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-hibernate,/sbin/reboot,/sbin/poweroff,/sbin/ctrlaltdel
```

Now, with the `timestamp_timeout=10` minutes, users can still issue password requiring commands without password if it is within the timeout period.

Other than **timestamp_timeout=0**, is there any other way to enforce users to enter password **every time** they issue specific commands (like reboot in the above list)?

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195719/how-do-i-force-sudo-to-ask-for-a-password-each-time-when-a-specific-command-is